# Pray and Hope That

Tags: present-subjunctive

Are the following sentences grammatical if I don't know whether "he" is doing well or not right now?

- I pray he be doing well now
- I hope he be doing well now

I know the verb 'hope' is used with indicative mood in Modern English but I have seen it can take subjunctive as well.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to use a subjunctive.  Unfortunately this makes you sound like someone from 200 years ago, or in particular it makes you sound like a "Pirate of the Caribbean".  Modern English doesn't have much use for subjunctive:

> I pray that he's doing well now

> I hope he's doing well now.

Comment: I know they are rare but i just wanted to know if they are grammatically correct

Comment: Not correct, not in modern English.

Comment: Maybe "grammatical" in some strict academic sense, but to our modern ears they sound *verrry* strange and wrong. James K is correct. It sounds like the way we imagine people spoke long ago - 200 years *or more*.